# How to add non-bazel project as a build target for current bazel project?

Tags: bazel, envoyproxy, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

Background:
I have a  C++ header-only library eg : mpack
mpack uses cmake build system. However, I want to use some of its functions in my project (my_project) which uses bazel build system.

I was following the steps from
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/1.2.0/external.html#non-bazel-projects

Goal:
Trying to include mpack.hpp in sni_filter.cc

My changes:

a) Added the following snippet in WORKSPACE file

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "mpack-c",
    path = "mpack-c",
    build_file = "BUILD.mpack-c",
)
```

b) Added BUILD.mpack-c

```
cc_library(
    name = "mpack-lib",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

c) Added the mpack-lib target in BUILD file of sni_filter

```
envoy_cc_library(
    name = "sni_filter_lib",
    srcs = ["sni_filter.cc"],
    hdrs = ["sni_filter.h"],    
    deps = [       
        "@mpack-c//:mpack-lib",
    ],
)
```

When I am trying to run a bazel build, its throwing an error :

```
ERROR: Error fetching repository: /xoxo/xyz/abc/repo/src/engine/WORKSPACE:28:21: In new_local_repository rule //external:mpack-c the 'build_file' attribute does not specify an existing file (/xoxo/xyz/abc/repo/src/engine/BUILD.mpack-c does not exist)
ERROR: /xoxo/xyz/abc/repo/src/engine/my_proj/sni_filter/BUILD:11:17: //my_proj/sni_filter:sni_filter_lib depends on @mpack-c//:mpack-lib in repository @mpack-c which failed to fetch. no such package '@mpack-c//': In new_local_repository rule //external:mpack-c the 'build_file' attribute does not specify an existing file (/xoxo/xyz/abc/repo/src/engine/BUILD.mpack-c does not exist)
```

Attached the directory struct
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The path in the `new_local_repository` attribute needs to either be absolute or relative to the directory the `WORKSPACE` file is located in. Also, the label in the `build_file` attribute needs to specified relative to the workspace root.

So, in your `WORKSPACE` file replace:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "mpack-c",
    path = "mpack-c",
    build_file = "BUILD.mpack-c",
)
```

with:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "mpack-c",
    path = "mpack",
    build_file = "mpack/BUILD.mpack-c",
)
```

For reference, see the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository).